# How to handle multiple database access Using AngularJs...?

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs application i want use multiple databases.One database is located my local server and second database is located on remote server.

How to get/post data from/to remote server and access on my application..?

Comment: you cant access remote database from angularjs but I guess you are trying to use web services/apis. For that you can use `$http` or `$resource` services provided by angularjs.

Comment: ok i will use backend php and mysql  is it possible to use databses..?

Comment: You will handle connection to db, querying db and responding the incoming request in php(backend), lets say in `list-users.php` . Now you'll send HTTP GET request to that file using any of angularjs services that I mention in my earlier comment. which will look something like $http.get('http://localhost/list-users.php').success(function(){}).error(function(){}) ...

and have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service wich is designed for this purpose. Then just precise for each resource which database to connect to.

```
var getFromServerOne = $resource('http://server-one.com/foo', {...});
var getFromServerTwo = $resource('http://server-two.com/bar', {...});
```

Comment: ok but where did i specify the server two database authentication credentials..?

Comment: I had a similar situation, and our API-s used Authorization header parameter for validation, so before calling different API we needed to set different autoriazation header. $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ... and than to call second API.